Removing all but the first letter of every word using regex in LibreOffice Writer
I have found a couple posts around the internet and on here on how to remove all but the first letter of every word in a paragraph (or the whole text) using regex and Microsoft Word, but nothing has seemed to work in LibreOffice Writer.
I have been trying to use the Find and Replace dialog and have regular expressions checked in the options.
As an example:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Would become:
L i d s a, c a e, s d e t i u l e d m a.
Keeping punctuation and case sensitivity would be great. I also am not opposed to using a different method/program for this.

Both Flash's and Tim's solutions work, but while I have a fondness for regular expressions that replace matches with empty strings (Tim's answer), Flash's solution is seen to be more efficient: 114 versus 452 steps for the test string.

@CarySwoveland seems @mordock's own find is even better: \B[a-z]+ or \B\w+ would be 75 steps or 76 steps (not sure why the difference)

Assuming LibreOffice's regex support fixed width lookbehinds, you could match on the following pattern:
(?<=\w)\w

and then replace with empty string.  This pattern will match any word character except those not preceded by word characters (e.g. at the start of a word).
Here is a running demo.p
Edit:
As suggested in the comments, we can optimize the pattern to:
(?<=\w)\w+

This will match entire sub-words in one go, reducing the number of replacement steps.

libreoffice does support this. (?<=\w)\w+ might be more efficient.

Yes, this worked. There are a couple formatting issues with numbers and the like, but I have no problems fixing those by hand. Also, \B[a-z] seems to give the same results, which I had just figured out and was coming to update my question with that information. Thank you!

Further to @jhnc's suggestion, for the test string, it is seen that replacing \w with \w+ reduces the number of matches from  83 to 19 and the number of steps from 452 to 132.

Use find and replace and check the regex (Regular expressions) checkbox.
Search for: \b(\w)\w+,
replace with: $1

\b is a word boundary anchor that ensures the match starts at the beginning of a word.
(\w) captures the first letter of the word and makes it the first group
\w+ matches the rest of the word, which will be replaced.
$1 in the replace field inserts the first captured group (the first letter in our case).


This solution works for the first word of a paragraph, but unfortunately fails to change any words thereafter, unless it's a new paragraph.

Weird. Works in my case. But you could try (\b\w)\w* then.
